# How can I get a Zend Framework project to run on IIS?

Tags: php, zend-framework, iis

I am trying to get the Zend Framework (ver 9 Studio) to deploy and actually run on my local IIS server.

I have created a very simple little app using the built-in wizard.  It works fine if I run it on the Apache server that comes with Zend.  But I tried to copy the files over and run it on IIS, and I get errors.

It appears that it is missing the links to the libraries.  I've tried manually isolating and grabbing the missing libraries and putting them into the /library folder.  This is a good start but I still get other errors down the road.

I found a tutorial out there that comes with an example of a Zend Project that runs in IIS.  But, it pretty much has the same problems as the project I created.  More missing libraries.  The tutorial includes some neat new tricks like a web.config that is supposed to replace the need for the .htaccess that Apache uses.

That's how far I've made it.  This is all very frustrating.  Does anyone have a simple example like that tutorial promised?  If not, just some good information would be helpful.

Comment: Is PHP installed correctly to run on IIS?

Comment: Did you compare the ini settings on each install/machine for include_path ?

Comment: Yes, it is.  In fact, I can run straight PHP without the Zend Framework.  I even have my connection string for the database working fine.  So, it's definitely not the server.  I have both Apache and IIS running.  And they don't interfere with one another.

Cups - what should the include_path be, and where do I set it?

Comment: Do you have the libraries in the library folder and have that set as the include path?

Comment: I have libraries in the /library folder, but I do not know where to set the include_path.

Answer (score 0):

you need the rewrite module, [Rob Allen has a little tutorial](http://akrabat.com/winphp-challenge/zend-framework-url-rewriting-in-iis7/) to help. The biggest problem is usually the rewrite module, because you have to install it seperately.

Comment: Yep...  I found that tutorial, and I installed that rewrite module.  But since the libraries aren't there, the code doesn't even make it far enough for that to execute.

Comment: what libraries? Remeber Zend Studio and Zend Framework are not related except that they are both made by Zend. Zend Framework is a stand alone framework. Put it on your PHP include path or in the application/library under the folder Zend and it will work. The only issues that ZF has with IIS is the rewrite module. You do have to make sure that php is installed to work with iis http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=PHP53